# How to trim the array if length is > 5

Tags: angular, typescript

How to trim the array if length is > 5

My JSON is:

```
{
        "name": "aaa"
        "files": [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "link": "string.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "Q",
                "link": "string.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "M",
                "link": "string.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "New Filters Reports",
                "link": "string.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "U",
                "link": "string.com"
            }
        ],
        "titles": [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F"
        ]
    }
```

I want to check if "titles" length is greater than 5, it should trim the values after 5 and should display only 5 titles on screen.

Comment: assuming the json is in a variable like myArray, you could say myArray.titles.length = 5

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to keep the full array in your logic, and only trim it in your HTML. If this is the case, just use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) where you want to display the trimmed list.

I.e.

```
<div *ngFor="let i of arr.slice(0,5)">
  {{i}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice for that.

```
let trimmed = data.titles.slice(0, 5);
```