# typescript and Angular5: How to trim array if length is < 5

Tags: angular, typescript

How to trim the array if length is < 5

My JSON is:

```
[
{
        "type": "aaa"
        "values": [
            {
                "risk": "A"
            },
            {
                "risk": "Q"
            },
            {
                "risk": "M"
            },
            {
                "risk": "New Filters Reports"
            },
            {
                "name": "U"
            },
            {
                "risk": "U"
            },
            {
                "risk": "U"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have to display only 5 **"values"** on my HTML. How do I trim **"values.risk"** after 5 numbers?

Comment: You have asked exactly the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268846/how-to-trim-the-array-if-length-is-5) 10 minutes ago. What's wrong with that one?

Comment: Instead of asking same question again and again , UPdate the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the first `n` elements of an array using `slice`.

```
var items = myValues.slice(0, 5);
```

Full example:

```js
    var obj = [
        {
            "type": "aaa",
            "values": [
                {
                    "risk": "A"
                },
                {
                    "risk": "Q"
                },
                {
                    "risk": "M"
                },
                {
                    "risk": "New Filters Reports"
                },
                {
                    "name": "U"
                },
                {
                    "risk": "U"
                },
                {
                    "risk": "U"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    
    const firstFive = obj[0].values.slice(0, 5);
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(firstFive));
```